# ListView Properties SearchVisible=true , ItemIndex no longer usable

Tags: listview, delphi

On an Android device, I have a ListView, which I populate with data. I allow the user to search through this using the built-in `SearchVisible` property.

The problem is, if I search (filter) the list, the `ItemIndex` does not take this into account.

This no longer works correctly:

```
procedure TCDP.ListView1Gesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Length(Customers) = 0 then Exit;

  if EventInfo.GestureID = igiDoubleTap then
  begin
    ShowMessage(Customers[ListView1.Selected.Index].AH_NAME1);
  end;
end;
```

Is this doable somehow?

Comment: The `TListItem.Index` is relative to the current display, so if you are filtering items, the indexes won't match the `Customers` list. I suggest you use the `TListViewItem.Tag` property to keep track of the `Customers` indexes, or even pointers to the `Customers` objects, on a per-item basis. Then the `TListItem.Index` won't matter.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much Remy!!!